# Angular update data inside ng-template with ngIf and Observable

Tags: angular, observable, ng-template

**the template:**

```
<ng-template #rightPanelContent>
  <si-right-panel-content [heading]="">
    <h1>HEAD No NGIF</h1>
      <div *ngIf="cpDevices$ | async as cpDevices">
       ...
      </div>
  </si-right-panel-content>
</ng-template>
```

**ViewChild:**

```
  @ViewChild('rightPanelContent', { static: false }) set setrightPanelContent( rightPanelContent: TemplateRef<unknown>) {
    if(rightPanelContent){
      console.log("ViewChild updated");
      this.rightPaneltemplate = new TemplatePortal(
        rightPanelContent,
        this._viewContainerRef
      );
    }
  }
```

I need to set the right panel content with updated data when clicking on a button, but the problem is that the right panel content is updated after calling the function which handles the button click.
I only need to inject this line in the right position (after the update).

```
this.rightPanelService.setRightPanelContent(this.rightPaneltemplate);
```

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution that works using TemplatePortal:

```
      ngAfterViewInit () {
        this.rightPaneltemplate = new TemplatePortal(
          this.rightPanelContent,
          this._viewContainerRef
        );
```

set the right panel content with updated data when clicking on a button

```
    this.rightPanelService.setRightPanelContent(this.rightPaneltemplate);
```

then it's important to track the cpDevices$ observable value using the BehaviorSubject

@component:

```
private readonly cpDeviceWithSensorsSub = new BehaviorSubject<CpDevices>(undefined);

constructor(){
...
this.cpDevices$ = this.cpDeviceWithSensorsSub.asObservable();
}

ngOnInit() {
...
        this.cpDeviceSubscription = (// when receive the data//).subscribe(value => this.cpDeviceWithSensorsSub.next(value));
}
```

[Angular templatePortal docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview#templateportal)